# Series of datetime string to string format %d-%m-%Y

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

What I'm looking for is a dataframe that has a date column, but it does not have the data type datetime64ns, it currently has type object with the following format YYYY-mm-DD I need to change this format to d-m-Y

```
0     2019-05-14 
1     2019-05-14
2     2019-05-14
3     2019-05-14
4     2019-05-14
```

`dataframe['fefuente'].apply(lambda x: f'{x:%d-%m-%Y}')`
 
I currently have this code, but I get the following error ValueError: Invalid format specifier

what he sought to obtain is something like this

```
0     14-05-2019
1     14-05-2019
2     14-05-2019
3     14-05-2019
4     14-05-2019
```

Comment: pd.to_datetime(s).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

Comment: @WeNYoBen Is there a real need to first convert the column to datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to convert the column to a datetime object.

```
dataframe['fefuente'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['fefuente'])
```

Then, as WeNYoBen said, you format the datetime.

```
dataframe['new_date']= dataframe['fefuente'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: Is there a real need to first convert the column to datetime?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise, Pandas will not be capable of formating it to the desired date.